# Delegate doesn't respond

Tags: swift

im trying to call a method which is in ViewController from my custom UIView class but the delegate doesn't print the text.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, MenuButtonDelegate {
     func changeNodeColor(_ color: UIColor?){
            print("delegate called")
        }

    }
```

and my custom UIView class

```
protocol MenuButtonDelegate: class {
    func changeNodeColor(_ color: UIColor?)
}


class MenuButton: UIView {
var delegate: MenuButtonDelegate?
```

here I call it after button is touched like this

```
   delegate?.changeNodeColor(UIColor.black)
```

Whats wrong with that? Thank you

Comment: You have to **set** the delegate somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ViewController you need to say `menuButton.delegete = self` then it should work